# Error querying database from PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, insert

I am trying to insert a row of data into a table from PHP. However I'm getting an error message from the below code, saying:

> "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli"

```
$myServer = "mysql.x90x.net";
$myUser = "u1908429**_*****";
$myPass = "***************";
$myDB = "u1908429**_*****";
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass, $myDB)
    or die("Couldn't connect to SQL server on $myServer.");
$query = "INSERT INTO student_data VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$gpaP', '$agP', '$awardP', '$awardTP', '$rigorP', '$APP')"; 
$result = mysqli_query($query, $dbhandle)
    or die(mysql_error().'<br>SQL:'.$query);
mysqli_close($dbhandle);
```

I think its saying something is wrong with the `mysqli_query` but I don't know what's wrong?...

Answer (score 2):

You pass the query to the first parameter and handle to the second when It should be the opposite.

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $query);
```

---

I recommend you to consult the documentation when having similar problems. It's not hard.

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

The [documentation](http://php.net/mysqli_query) is actually really nice and gives you good explanation of all the parameters that a function expect.

Answer (score 0):

What about mysqli_select_db($link, "dbname"); ?
AFAIK mysqli needs that so dbhandle should be return of this function.

Comment: He tells mysqli which database to use in `mysqli_connect` (last parameter) so no problem there.